How close to the edge of an interior door should a magnetic catch be?
I just had my interior doors replaced with solid core doors, and one of them is a double door. I purchased a magnetic catch to keep the passive door secure (instead of using a ball catch). This is the one I purchased:
https://www.precisionlockservices.com/productsPLS24.html
My question is how far from the edge of the passive door, horizontally speaking, should the magnet be or does it not matter too much?
Here are some photos to explain what I mean. Should the magnet be placed on the red line (assuming the closer to the edge of the door, the better) or would placing it on the blue line work just as well? Or should it be even further away from the edge? Not sure what the rule of thumb is:


Based on the example pictures on the manufacturer's site, it looks maybe like 2 or 2.5 inches from the edge of the door but it's hard to tell for sure. In my photos, the blue line is roughly 2 inches away from the edge, so should I place it there or should I remove the surface bolt catch and place it on the red line? I'm probably going to remove the surface bolt anyway since it's crooked and probably will never be used but maybe the blue line is more appropriate (or maybe even further away from the blue line...or maybe I am just overthinking it in general ).

IMO, the closer it is to the hinge, the more sensitive it will be to precise positioning of door closure.

@Huesmann Thank you, that does make sense, so definitely not the red line in my photos at least. It's just hard to pick the ideal spot. I've since watched some videos on ball latch installations since they're more common and one person mentioned going just past the first "column" of the door for lack of a better word (the long narrow section on either side of most doors)

Personally, I would use the red line location.  Are you referring to the stile (what you refer to as "column")?

@Huesmann oh I see I misunderstood what you said then as I thought you meant the closer to the hinge side, the better (red line in the photo is closer to the handle side of the door). And yes stile is the appropriate word, thank you (today I learned lol).
I was referencing this video where the gentlemen mentions ball catches are usually placed beyond the stile closest to the handle side, but those are ball catches and not sure if this is really a "standard" practice per se VIDEO LINK

Ball and mag catches have the same sensitivity to closure, IMO.
